# Any way to skip a formatter token when using String.format()?

Tags: java, string-formatting, string.format

I have a `String myString = "%d New Voicemail";`

**I'd like to do this for 2:**

```
String myString = "%d New Voicemail";
System.out.println(String.format(myString, 2));
```

**Output: 2 New Voicemail**

---

**I'd like to do this for 5:**

```
String myString = "%d New Voicemail";
System.out.println(String.format(myString, 5));
```

**Output: 5 New Voicemail**

---

**I'd like to do this for 1:**

```
String myString = "%d New Voicemail";
System.out.println(String.format(myString));
```

**Output: CRASH**

**Expected output: New Voicemail**

---

As you can see, for "1" I just want to display the string without formatting. If I just leave out the extra param it crashes. Is there a simple solution I'm unaware of?

I can do this, but wondering if theres a simpler way:

```
int num;
if (num == 1){
    System.out.println(myString.subString(3));

} else {
    System.out.println(String.format(myString, num));

}
```

Comment: Of course you can use `System.out.printf()` instead of `println`. But that won’t answer your question.

Comment: Why do you want to omit the 1 in case there's only one new voicemail? Wouldn't it be easier (while also correct) to just show "1 New Voicemail"? Unless it's an academic excercise, it looks like you're striving to solve a non-existing problem.

Comment: @GiulioFranco Not academic. It's what the design team wants. Out of my control. I'm just trying the best way to implement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While it is not OK to pass fewer arguments to `printf` than is expected by the format line, it's OK to pass more arguments. You can use a conditional expression for the format line itself, like this:

```
System.out.printf(num != 1 ? myString : myString.substring(3), num);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/x0wjBh)

Comment: This solution, by the way, is just as bad as the one that I posted myself. In real life, there should be two separated strings for singular and plural, to distinguish between “1 new voicemail” and “5 new voicemails”. And for I18N, you shouldn’t even assume that two versions are enough.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel Of course - anything posted on Stack Overflow should be taken as an illustration, not as a production-ready code. Making this language-agnostic takes the code to a whole another level - now one must not assume that "plural" is the same for all numbers greater than `1`. For example, in Russian the string would be different for numbers ending in 1, numbers ending in 2, 3, or 4, and numbers ending in 5 and up, including zero, but excluding the "...teen" numbers.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel although people have tried to include it, as the question states, I don't need to distinguish singluar vs plural. So in this case this answer is correct. I am selecting this as the best answer, because you did answer the fact that "it is not OK to pass fewer args...".

Comment: Of course, if your intention was not to alter the original string, then this answer will have a linebreak missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
System.out.printf("%s New Voicemail%n", num == 1 ? "" : num);
```

Comment: Why don’t you just try? :-) Of course it will compile, Java will handle it by automatically applying `toString()`. The type of `?:` is determined by the first operand. It’s similar to `"1" + 1`.

Comment: That's not what quite what happens http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25

Comment: Cool, my comment doesn’t make any sense whatsoever now that the comment it answered disappeared. Well. And it was an oversimplification. Well.

Answer (score 0):

This is, of course, the extreme technique. But, once set up, it is simple to use, and the design team will not have any reason to grumble.

```
static String voicemail( int n ){
    MessageFormat form = new MessageFormat("{0}");
    double[] filelimits = {0,1,2};
    String[] filepart = {"No New Voicemail",
             "New Voicemail",
             "{0,number} New Voicemails"};
    ChoiceFormat fileform = new ChoiceFormat(filelimits, filepart);
    form.setFormatByArgumentIndex(0, fileform);
    Integer[] values = new Integer[]{n};
    return form.format( values );
}
```

Test:

```
for( int i = 0; i <=3; ++i ){
    System.out.println( voicemail(i) );
}
```

Output.

```
No New Voicemail
New Voicemail
2 New Voicemails
3 New Voicemails
```

Comment: Yeah, the reason I need to be able to use a string and a formatter hard coded is for localization purposes. In certain languages the formatter shows up in different locations. Appreciate the answer though.

Comment: The filepart components could be localized.

Comment: Noted. I believe I'll be going for a simpler solution. +1 for probably the most complete answer for most people. I fortunately don't need to make any comparison for singular vs plural, and the goal of this exercise was to reuse a String I already have so that we don't have to send out new strings to be localized. Again, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: this is not answering the question how to do it with format!

Answer (score -1):

Since you *want* to use two different instructions to print 1 or >1 voicemails, it's clear that you *must* have an `if` somewhere in your program. That's where you can change your format.

```
String format = "New Voicemail";
if (num == 1){
  System.out.println(myString);
} else {
  System.out.println(String.format("%d " + format, 5));
}
```